# A jar contains n red and n green marbles

Tags: permutations, combinations

I'm so confused with the question below and I do appreciate your help:)

A jar contains n red and n green marbles where n>=2. You pick two marbles from the jar.

Q: Number of ways to pick one of each color (   ) n^2

A.>

B.<

C.=

D.cannot be determined

I think the answer should be C, but it turns out to be A at least in my exercise book:(

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: (additionally -- where does the keyword "probability" come from? There is no probability at play in your question.)

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I misunderstand something. I add this because it's from the exercise in the big section of probability. So is that related to combination?

Comment: Yes, it's more combinatorics than anything else. Also, the question is very unclear and ambiguous -- are you positive you copied it verbatim?

Comment: Yes, I just checked that. Also, it doesn't provide any explanation for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

They are counting red-green as different from green-red, so there are $2n^2$ ways to get one of each.  I don't think the question is clear.

Comment: The last sentence, I fully agree... and it's an understatement.

Answer (score 1):

So, how many ways are there to pick marbles in general? First, (assuming without replacement), you choose the first marble from $2n$ marbles. Then, you choose the second marble. There are $2n-1$ marbles left. Thus, you hace $2n(2n-1)$ ways of choosing the marbles.

Next, consider choosing your first marble. It can be any color, so you have $2n$ choices - it doesn't matter which marble you choose. For the second marble, you MUST choose a different color. There are $2n-1$ marbles left, but $n$ of the color you didn't already choose. So you have $2n^2$ ways of choosing.

$2n^2>n^2$, so $A$ is, indeed, the answer.

Comment: This is under a few assumptions: distinct marbles, without replacement.

Comment: Thank you for your help:) I'm aware that the question is somewhat unclear, so in spite of some assumptions, your answer does help me to get a better understanding of the answer. Many thanks again.